# Unsolved Problems in Number Theory Problems

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, soft-question

I hope for a few answers, my question is what happens if a person solves a problem in Guy's ,Unsolved Problems in Number Theory? I know know that onsome level it depends on the problem. But just in general is that going to boost ones career or is it seen as just decent? I just hope for a rich answer or if you know someone personally who solved a problem in the book and how it affected them.

Comment: As you note, it will depend on the problem. It will also depend on the solution (does it generalize? is it just a numerical counterexample). Any solution will be a boost. Whether a significant boost depends ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difficulty level of the problems in UPINT varies tremendously. Some of them have been found to have simple solutions; others are some of the most notorious unsolved problems in mathematics. So there's no blanket answer to "what happens when one solves a UPINT problem".

As a baseline, I would say that the outcome is commensurate with what the outcome would be for a problem and solution of a similar level that didn't appear in UPINT. Then add one minor notch-of-goodness, because it is helpful to be able to say "this problem appeared in UPINT"; that's a sign that some mathematicians at least had thought about the problem and found it interesting and challenging.

For an established mathematician, one minor notch isn't a big deal. For a newcomer, that minor bump might be relatively significant. But in the end, it's just an adjustment to the "instrinsic" goodness of the problem and solution (which, of course, is already pretty subjective).